# Booting to a black screen without cursor in Windows 10

Tags: boot, windows-10

**Background**:

Ever since I upgraded to Windows 10 half a year ago, my computer has sometimes not been able to wake up from sleep. It was infrequent enough that I ignored it (that said, it happened around maybe 2-5 times a month). Yesterday, the same thing occured, and not wanting to restart I tried tipping the tower. This actually got me my screen back when I set it back down. Its behaviour was super weird however--it was kind of unresponsive, I was at the login screen and, after typing a bit of my password, it automatically went and tried to sign me in. It was taking too long so I tipped the tower again, and it went back to the login screen. This half-logging-in + waiting forever thing happened two more times before I gave up and did a hard restart.

Then the computer said that it was doing some system checks and recovery. I waited for it to finish, but it was eventually just at a black screen with a cursor. I restarted again and this time, nothing came up--just a black screen, not even a cursor this time.

**Attempted fixes:**

Today I cleaned the inside of my tower, especially the video card, and did a bios reset, but it's still booting to a black screen without cursor. It goes as far as the screen with the blinky underscore before all display disappears. The fans are running, I've never gotten any error messages or beeps during the boot sequence, but nothing is displayed no matter how long I wait. Also ran `chkdsk /f` on all my drives and did a memory test too.

I also can't get into safe mode. I've tried creating a repair image with my USB--it always says that it couldn't repair my computer, and it does not have that "Windows Startup Settings" option websites everywhere are telling me to click in order to boot to the safe mode selection menu.

How do I fix this?

**Edit**: So I finally thought to look at the log for why startup repair kept failing, and what was the root cause? "Boot status indicates that the OS booted successfully"...

Comment: Sounds like a hardware failure that had very little to do with the upgrade to Windows 10.  How I know it's a hardware problem,  tipping a computer, cannot solve a software problem

Comment: Would you have a guess on what that hardware failure could be? All the hardware I have (save for the motherboard) is pretty new, just around half a year old. In regards to relevance with Win 10, I have not ever tipped the tower before yesterday, but was still getting "can't wake up from sleep" errors.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? This has become a huge problem for thousands of people from the latest windows "anniversary" update... no solutions yet. If you have 2 monitors you will get a black screen. If you have monitors using VGA you will get a black screen. Basically you have to update your display drivers but you can't because the screen is black so you can't navigate windows at all TO update... UG wtf windows

Comment: @Kayvar Unfortunately I just ended up building a new computer. To this day I'm not sure what went wrong, but I had been using my HDD for around 8 years at the point when I posted this so that might have been part of the problem (I bought an ssd and used it as my OS drive for the new build--that said, the old HDD did continue working as a storage drive for a few more weeks). Before this I had attempted to replace my graphics card and RAM to no avail, so in my case it /was/ probably just the HDD getting old and getting deader when I gently tipped the case it was in.

Comment: I got this twice (on my two computers, about the same time) last year, ended up reinstalling completely both (had to do again for the Surface Pro, other than that working fine). Today a third computer failed, same symptom  "Boot status indicates that the OS booted successfully"... So either I find the solution and share, or add another full reinstall "Solution"

Comment: @BrunoGuardia Damn that's brutal. Given how many people there seem to be still suffering from this problem after almost one and a half years, if you can figure out an actual solution you would be the saviour to us all so please try (and share if found!).